# List view, display text vertically

Tags: c#, listview

Is there any way to get a list view to display vertically?  Rigth now for my list view, the view is "List", but if there are too many entries, then you have to scroll to the right to view the rest, I just want to be able to scroll down to see the rest.

I tried all the other options, but they don't seem to work.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think to get the effect you want, you need to set the view to "Details", then add a single column (either through the designer or in code).

This is what I do in mine:

```
SelectionList.View = View.Details;
SelectionList.HeaderStyle = ColumnHeaderStyle.None;
SelectionList.Columns.Add(new ColumnHeader { Width = SelectionList.ClientSize.Width - SystemInformation.VerticalScrollBarWidth });
```

Then to add items:

```
foreach (var item in _collectionOfSomething)
{
      SelectionList.Items.Add(new ListViewItem(item.ItemName) {Tag = item.Ident});
}
```

Comment: How do i add a single column?

Comment: So the issue I have with Detials view, is when I try and add something to the list box, it doesn't display.  Where as in the view "list", it works.

Comment: Thank you so much.  I fiddled around too long with a listbox until deciding to switch over to listview after seeing this, along with the ease of changing the background color (BackColor) property.